# Code reordering by compiler across mutex boundaries

Tags: c++, locking, mutex

Consider the following code:

```
int a = 0, b = 0;
boost::mutex m;
a++;
m.lock();
m.unlock();
b++;
```

What locks do is that they tell the compiler "ok, forget about the C++ standard for a moment, I don't care what optimizations it would have allowed if you'd followed that strictly. You must NOT reorder any memory accesses across this boundary". Does this mean that `a++;` will always happen before `b++;`? Or does it mean that, if there was a statement s, between the locks, don't reorder that with `a++` or `b++`?

Comment: Given the compiler can see `a` and `b` are local variables, it can optimize on them as usual. In the given code, there is no way another thread can see the `int`s in question, so the mutex doesn't affect them.

Comment: @BaummitAugen  What about `global variable`? Will the compiler re-oder the two reads into one for a  `global variable`.For example, if (!g_is_log_file_ready)
{
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(Logger::g_log_mutex);
if (!g_is_log_file_ready)
{
Logger::g_log_stream.open("sdk.log", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
g_is_log_file_ready = true;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is already well answered by Baum mit Augen's comment.

However, if "a" and "b" were **global** variables, and declared **volatile**, depending on the compiler the memory barrier imposed by the mutex may guarantee that read/write expressions will not be reordered across the boundary.

This means that a thread that reads "b" and discovers it has been increased, and after this performs similar mutex locking to impose a memory barrier, and finally reads "a", is guaranteed to find that "a" has been modified as well.

MSVC has this behavior, and some other compilers as well.